# Is it possible to write an iPhone app which can be active while the person is making a call, and "talk" to the person on the other end?

Tags: iphone, mobile, voip, voice

For instance, the app could say something like, "Please wait." or "I'll be right back".  A friend asked me if it was possible, and since I don't have an iPhone I couldn't answer the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that would require the third party app to be active while the phone app was active, which is not currently possible. Third-party (developer created) apps are open when they are open and then quit when some other app is open.

Comment: You can run a third party app while the phone app is active.  You just can't play a sound out through the phone app to the other end.  I just tried this and I could get sounds played back through Bluetooth since the phone was active and sounds were being routed to the bluetooth headset.

Comment: To be clear, you can't run the phone app without quitting all other apps. Once the phone app is dialing, you can leave it, and the call is still active, and enter a third party app.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Devin what you ask for isn't possible, the only option would be for you app to handle the communication, but as the Google Voice debacle has shown that might be hard to get approved. Then again, Skype and other VOIP apps did get approved so if you're interested in going that route you might have some luck, but you can't work with normal phone calls.

Of course once you start wanting the app to actually 'talk' to the person it gets even more complex, since you're now asking for text-to-speech capability. Once again it's possible, but not with a normal phone call.